# Formal alternative for "dos and don'ts"

Tags: phrase-requests, formality, writing

I want to write "dos and don'ts", or an equivalent expression, in a university essay. I am assuming that it is not very academic to write "dos and don'ts", so does anyone have a better way of putting it?

Comment: They used to be called 'rules' or 'guidelines'.

Comment: **"Compulsories and Forbiddens"**?

Answer (score 4):

How about **Best Practice** which you can use to encompass a set of recommendations as well as a set of things to advise against.

> The *best practice* for goldfish degaussing is described below ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[what is allowed and  what is not](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=authorized+and+what+is+not%2Callowed+and+what+is+not%2Cpermitted+and+what+is+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Callowed%20and%20what%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpermitted%20and%20what%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0)."

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the expression "*The Do's and Don'ts*"<sub>[“Do's” and “don'ts” ..?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28671/dos-and-donts-or-dos-and-donts/28680#28680)</sub> and place it within inverted commas (speech marks) in your essay, it has the advantage of being well-known and self-explanatory but much would depend on the topic being discussed and who your reader is.

Otherwise, the expression **recommendations** could be used; it's formal and can include indicted courses of action as well as contradicted ones.

> **I would recommend not to** follow this line. To deny citizenship to hundreds of thousands non-Latvians residing in Latvia is tantamount to
>   refusing to grant them political rights, and this, in turn would,
>   sooner or later, have negative repercussions ... <sub>[source](http://books.google.it/books?id=EiTBKJNFAsUC&pg=PA717&dq=%22I%20would%20recommend%20not%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ARJaU6GwJ6WkyAPTzYHIAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20would%20recommend%20not%20to%22&f=false)</sub>

> ... and to keep the interest rate at a stipulated amount, **I recommend not
>   to** exceed 5 percent... <sub>[source](http://books.google.it/books?id=eyTRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22I%20recommend%20not%20to%22&dq=%22I%20recommend%20not%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=khNaU4XWGubaygPCkYGgAw&redir_esc=y)</sub>